# Sublime Text Python with Terminus seems to interfere with file handling

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext3, file-handling, build-system

I'm running this short bit of code:

```
import os
if os.path.exists("demofile.txt"):
    print("file exists")
else:
    print("file does not exist")
```

with the file "demofile.txt" in the same directory as my python file.

If I use this Python3 build system:

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "python3 -OO -u \"$file\"",
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python.3",
    "windows":
    {
        "shell_cmd": "py -3 -OO -u \"$file\""
    }
}
```

My output displays:

```
file exists
[Finished in 0.0s]
```

But, if I use the same Python3 build system with Terminus added in:

```
{
    "target": "terminus_exec",
    "cancel": "terminus_cancel_build",

    "focus": true,
    
    "shell_cmd": "python3 -OO -u \"$file\"",
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python.3",
    "windows":
    {
        "shell_cmd": "py -3 -OO -u \"$file\""
    }
}
```

My output displays:

```
file does not exist
[Finished in 0.08s]
```

other tests with file handling seem to have similar results, where the addition of terminus can't find files that exist.

Any thoughts on what might be going on here?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried setting `"working_dir": "$file_path"`?

Comment: The `exec` command used for normal builds will auto-populate the `working_dir` to be the path of the current file as @MattDMo outlined, whereas for `terminus_exec` the default is either the first folder open in the side bar or, failing that, your home directory. So without a `working_dir` setting in your build with Terminus, you need to have a very specific file layout for it to do what you want.

Comment: Aha! that did the trick! thank you both!